# Getting undefined variable roomId from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am getting an undefined variable message for roomId from PHP. I get it in an alertbox because I echoed it in PHP and alert the function in Javascript.

This is my ajax function:

```
function setMessages(roomId, username, message){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://www.sinansamet.nl/chatdistract/ajax/setMessages.php",
        data: { roomId:roomId, username:username, message:message },
        success: function(html) {
              alert(html);
                }
        });
}
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
$roomdId = $_GET['roomId'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$message = $_GET['message'];


echo $username;
?>
```

Calling ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", "#messageSubmit", function(){
    var username = window.localStorage["username"];
    var message = $("#message").val();
    setMessages(roomId, username, message);
    alert(roomId + username + message);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting undefined from ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971391/getting-undefined-from-ajax-call)

Comment: Where is `roomId` coming from in `setMessages(roomId, username, message);`?

Comment: You asked the exact same question 20 minutes ago

Comment: @Barmar Not really. That one was about a javascript error this is a PHP error and I didn't get an answer to that when I asked for it in the comments anymore. But still sorry about that I just really couldn't see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a typo i think. You wrote

```
$roomdId = $_GET['roomId'];
   //^there is an extra d
```

It should be

```
$roomId = $_GET['roomId'];
```

Comment: Omg thank you I can't believe I didn't notice that. I checked it so many times but couldn't see it. Time for new glasses I guess.

Comment: @SinanSamet don't worry, it happens sometimes. You are welcome dude.

Comment: @SinanSamet don't forget to accpet answer, you know how stackoverflow works!